# Detect if user has closed ALL windows for a website?

Tags: javascript, browser

I know about this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   //tell server user has left your site
};
```

but is there a client-side way to use javascript to detect if a user has closed **ALL** browser windows for your website?

Or do I need server-side code to detect this?

Comment: What you want is to know, in the onbeforeunload, if there's still an open tab ? In any browser or in the same browser ?

Comment: @NickDugger that's what `onbeforeunload` is for. It executes when the user closes the tab (That's how _Do you really want to leave this page?_ messages work.

Answer (score 6):

You can save an info into LocalStorage to detect any existence.

Some thoughts: on load you write the value to the sessionStorage:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (sessionStorage.instances) {
        sessionStorage = Number(sessionStorage.instances) + 1;
    } else {
        sessionStorage.instances = 1
    }
}
```

and on unload decrease the value:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var instances;

    if (sessionStorage.instances) {
        instances = Number(sessionStorage.instances) - 1;
        sessionStorage.instances = instances;
        if (0 === instances) {
            // all instances closed
        }
    }
}
```

Ciao
Ralf

PS: Example taken from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and modified a little ;)

Comment: +1 but don't forget to handle crashes (maybe with a mechanism like session timeout).

Comment: Ok, then you can use SessionStorage.

Comment: @RwamDev, thanks! Can you give an indication of how the code looks for `LocalStorage/SessionStorage`?

Comment: **Why downvotes?!** Answer can be improved with a small code example but it's substantially correct...

Comment: @RwamDev I did not downvote you +1 for the right idea. But wouldn't you need an event on the exact time each client has disconnected? Or will you just check for one instance on the start? I may overdone it, but here is an example of what could be working, but of course you can not rely on such a function: http://jsfiddle.net/BZTw3/4/

Comment: sessionStorage doesn't persist across tabs. Each new tab spawns a new session.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a cookie with prefix like closed_tab_ and suffix lets say either a timestamp or an uuid. When closing a window delete the cookie set by this tab and check for other cookies using the same naming scheme..
That should solve the problem even with browsers without local storage
As for crashed browsers - you can use a timer on every second to renew the cookie and set it to expire every second..
If you are not that time sensitive set it to larger value.