# Proper way to detect user's leaving page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web, websocket

I am building a WebApp (ERP) and I need to display the people currently logged in and active on the page. I managed to get something pretty accurate by listening on the mouse/keyboard events and periodically reporting to the DB.

I don't know how to mark people offline when they close the page. I tried using `onbeforeunload`, but it obviously fires when the user simply changes pages (click a link inside the ERP, that point to another page in the ERP).

I then tried to use `WebSockets`, but the problem is the same : everytime the page is realoded, the `WebSockets` connection is closed.

So I can think of two ways:

- Use `WebSockets` indeed, and replace *all links* by a call to a javascript function that would somehow *tell* the server that the user is going to change page (so that the server doesn't mark it as offline). **But that doesn't feel right**, semantically speaking, links should be *links*, it simply points to another location.
- Use either `WebSockets` or `AJAX` and never actually change page: links are replaces by a function that will call for the content, and display it on screen (updating the DOM with Javascript). But again, **it doesn't feel right either**, because semantically speaking the page would have no meaning **and** the URL would never change, so the user can't "copy paste" the link of the page to refer to it, right ?

So, is there a *proper, clean* way of doing this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of your pages has a webSocket connection to your server, then on the server you can see when any given page is closed by seeing that the webSocket gets closed.

To avoid thinking that a user has left the site when they are just navigating from one page in your site to another, you simply need to add a delay server-side so that you only report that the user has left your site if there has been no webSocket connection from this user for some time period (probably at least a few seconds).

So, on  your server when you detect that the last webSocket connection for this user has been closed, you set a timer for some number of seconds.  If the user opens up another page on your site (either via navigation or just opens another page) before the timer goes off, you cancel the timer and count the user as still connected.  If the timer goes off, then you now know that the user has been away from your site for whatever time period you picked (say 10 seconds) and to you, this will signify that they have left the site.  You can control how long you want that time period to be before you decide that, yes they are gone.

All attempts at trying to "see" the user leaving your page IN the browser with Javascript are going to have holes in them because there are always ways for a web page to get closed without your client-side javascript having a chance to tell your server.  The beauty of the webSocket solution is that the browser automatically and reliably tells your server when the page is now gone because it closes the webSocket and your server receives the notification that the socket has been closed.

Comment: Well... now that you mentionned this solution it seems obvious and I wonder why I did not think of that. **Of course** it seems like the _correct way_: I will combine this solution (to detect page close) and something like the answer below suggests to detect for inactivity on the page when the user doesn't do anything. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to compute users active on website/pages.

1. Identify the user (99% unique id computed): 
   http://valve.github.io/blog/2013/07/14/anonymous-browser-fingerprinting/ you can use another library, there are few.
2. On each page send from time to time at page load meaning user is navigating or (60sec you can chose lower time frame meaning user is staing on the page) computed id (fingerprint js) to server (web-socket/ajax)
3. On server you need to have list of id's with expiration date (60s) increment when new user log's in (stored in database or session).
4. Retrieve on your website the count (60sec ajax/websocket)  of id's having timestamp <= server time - let say 120sec.

Knowing if user is logged, and specify the page:

use an object to be sent at server {fingerprint: 123123124234, logged : true, page: home}

5. Clear your list if you are not storing in Database the users:

Separate thread (server only) access the object and destroy all nodes older then 10 min or whatever your page session is set.

js timer: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Let hope it's helpful, id did something similar using the timer at 5 min to sent to server if user is still on the page, or signal at page load.

Getting the cont of users in frame of 60 sec. And even the users with names present on page :)

Comment: Thanks, that was useful! Seems a bit complex, but I get the idea. I knew about browser fingerprinting and in this case it doesn't apply (the members can and will access the ERP from various computers) but thanks for providing a link : I'll keep that, this might prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody already post this kind of question.

Hope this could help you .

[Detect if user has closed ALL windows for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865561/detect-if-user-has-closed-all-windows-for-a-website)

Comment: Consider to use comments section for that kind of posts. Alternatively flag the question if you think that it may have been answered.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. @phillip100 Should I delete my answer now? I think it may break the rule .

Comment: Thank you @ronan for your link, but it doesn't solve my problem for when the user changes page. See below for answers.